# Lookup and sort the foreign collection

Tags: mongodb, optimization, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

so I have a collection `users`, and each document in this collection, as well as other properties, has an array of ids of documents in the other collection: `workouts`.
Every document in the collection `workouts` has a property named `date`.

And here's what I want to get:

> For a specific user, I want to get an array of {workoutId, workoutDate} for the workouts that belong to that user, sorted by date.

This is my attempt, which is working fine.

```
Users.aggregate([
    { 
        $match : {
            _id : ObjectId("whateverTheUserIdIs")
        }
    }, 
    { 
        $unwind : {
            path : "$workouts"
        }
    }, { 
        $lookup : {
            from : "workouts", 
            localField : "workouts", 
            foreignField : "_id", 
            as : "workoutDocumentsArray"
        }
    }, { 
        $project : {
            _id : false, 
            workoutData : {
                $arrayElemAt : [
                    $workoutDocumentsArray, 
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }, { 
        $project : {
            date : "$workoutData.date", 
            id : "$workoutData._id"
        }
    }, { 
        $sort : {date : -1}
    }
])
```

However I refuse to believe I need all this for what would be such a simple query in SQL!? I believe I must at least be able to merge the two `$project` stages into one? But I've not been able to figure out how looking at the docs.

Thanks in advance for taking the time! ;)

====
EDIT - This is some sample data

Collection users:

```
[{
  _id:xxx,
  workouts: [2,4,6]
 },{
  _id: yyy,
  workouts: [1,3,5]
}]
```

Colleciton workouts:

```
[{
  _id:1,
  date: 1/1/1901
 },{
  _id:2,
  date: 2/2/1902
 },{
  _id:3,
  date: 3/3/1903
 },{
  _id:4,
  date: 4/4/1904
 },{
  _id:5,
  date: 5/5/1905
 },{
  _id:6,
  date: 6/6/1906
 }]
```

And after running my query, for example for user xxx, I would like to get only the workouts that belong to him (whose ids appear in his workouts array), so the result I want would look like:

```
[{
  id:6,
  date: 6/6/1906
 },{
  id:4,
  date: 4/4/1904
 },{
  id:2,
  date: 2/2/1902
 }]
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data so it would be easier to explain.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Will do yeah, give me a sec

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet just added some more info, hope that makes sense now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `workouts` array as it already contains array of `_id`s and use [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) instead of doing [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

```
Users.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id" : ObjectId("whateverTheUserIdIs") }}, 
  { "$lookup": {
    "from" : "workouts", 
    "localField" : "workouts", 
    "foreignField" : "_id", 
    "as" : "workoutDocumentsArray"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$workoutDocumentsArray" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$workoutDocumentsArray" }}
  { "$sort" : { "date" : -1 }}
])
```

or even with new [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) syntax

```
Users.aggregate([
  { "$match" : { "_id": ObjectId("whateverTheUserIdIs") }}, 
  { "$lookup" : {
    "from" : "workouts", 
    "let": { "workouts": "$workouts" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$workouts"] }}},
      { "$sort" : { "date" : -1 }}
    ]
    "as" : "workoutDocumentsArray"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$workoutDocumentsArray" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$workoutDocumentsArray" }}
])
```